# unable to establish wifi connection

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu today and I cannot connect to my college wifi network. it is asking for BSSID which I don't know what it is. so please help me in establishing a connection.

Comment: Please give a bit more info about which steps you've taken and perhaps include a screenshot; this will greatly increase the chances of getting a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

BSSID is the MAC address of the access point. It will show up--e.g.--if you do something like

```
iwlist -scan wlan0
```

or

```
iwconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started ubuntu, click on the wifi signal icon in the bar on top. There you should see the name of the corresponding wifi network. Click it. If the wifi network is locked with WEP or WPA2 encryption, you should be able to enter the password there. I don't know why it would ask you for the BSSID.